# Does melee damage vary by weapon?

Tags: halo-combat-evolved

In the original Halo (and/or Anniversary), does your melee attack do a different amount of damage based on which weapon is equipped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the weapons do the same amount of melee damage. However they can vary in speed and accuracy (ease to hit the target).

The fastest weapons in melee are Plasma Pistol and Assault Rifle.
Source: http://strategywiki.org/wiki/Halo:_Combat_Evolved/Weapons

By the way, maybe this is interesting for you: [Double Melee Glitch](http://strategywiki.org/wiki/Halo:_Combat_Evolved/Glitches#Double_Melee)

Comment: Thanks! The double melee glitch is interesting, I had never heard of that

Answer (score 2):

Two hits from anywhere other than directly behind were required for a kill on the original Halo multiplayer. If you caught someone from behind, you would instantly kill them. Otherwise, first melee takes off the shields, second hit was a kill.

Comment: I don't think he is talking about multiplayer

Comment: Actually, if I remember it correctly, when playing Halo CE Anniversary in multiplayer with *classic settings* you need more than three hits in melee to kill a player